# Unable to open New tab in new its replacing the first tab rather than opening the new one in Firefox

Tags: selenium

```
public class TestTabs {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/Test/Downloads/geckodriver");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND+ "t");
    }

    @Test
    public void openSameUrlInMultipleTab() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://seleniumlearn.com/selenium-tutorial");
        {
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND+ "t");
            driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the above code to open multiple tabs in one browser but When I am running this code in Firefox (iMac mini) I am not getting any error message and code is passed but 2nd link is opening in same tab rather than in new tab. How can I open multiple tabs in Firefox in Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Each tab is considered as a new window. switch to the new tab using the `switch.to().window()`.

```
driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
driver.get("your new url goes here");
```

User below line if you want to switch to default browser (the base browser).

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: This is not working both URLs are opening in same tab. I want to open multi tabs

Comment: I am using Mac book